# Looking for a test to reproduce broken double checked locking

Tags: java, multithreading, double-checked-locking

Does anybody know of a test that reproduces "broken double checked locking" problem in java?

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckTest.java and see this article: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: Well the test isn't a problem. The problem is to find a platform and environment that maximizes likelihood of DCL failure. Unfortunately for you x86 has rather strong memory model :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this project: [java-concurrency-torture](https://github.com/shipilev/java-concurrency-torture). It is written by Alexey Shipilev. He is Java Performance Engineer who works at Oracle. Here is a [bunch of tests](https://github.com/shipilev/java-concurrency-torture/tree/master/src/main/java/org/openjdk/concurrent/torture/tests/singletons) for different kinds of singleton initialization practices.

**Important**: To maximize your chances to see DCL bug you should run these tests with `-server` flag on 32-bit jvm.